# Create an object with dynamic key name

Tags: typescript

How can I create an object like that?

```
{
    "dynamicName": {
        "name": "test",
        "city": "testCity"
    }
}
```

`name` and `city` properties are known, and `dynamicName` is supposed to be dynamic property

Comment: the type for it would be `Record<string, { name : string, city: string }>`

Comment: could you please provide an example how to make an assignment for such variable?

Comment: `var myObj: Record<string, { name : string, city: string }> = { dynamicName: { name: "test", city: "testCity" } }` or you could do `var myObj: Record<...> = {}; myObj["dynamicName"] = { name: "test", city: "testCity" };`

Comment: Do note that `Record<string, {name: string, city: string}>` is the same as `{[k: string]: {name: string, city: string}` and matches values like `{dynamicName: {name: "test", city: "testCity"}, anotherName: {name: "anotherTest", city: "anotherCity"}}` but not values like `{dynamicName: {name: "test", city: "testCity"}, otherProp: "hello"}`.